# Total no of sets in a list where a set is atleast 3 consecutive even numbers?

Tags: python, list, numbers

If I have a list of integers and I want to find the total number of sets in that list where a set is at least 3 consecutive even numbers?

**For example:**
list1 = [1,2,4,6,8,11,2,8]
has 1 such set because there is only 1 set (2,4,6,8) that has atleast 3 consecutive even numbers

My approach:

```
list1 = [1,2,4,6,8,11,2,8]
SetofEven = 0
for i in range(0,len(list1)-2):
    a, b, c = list1[i:i+3]
    if a%2 == b%2 == c%2 == 0:
        SetofEven = SetofEven + 1
```

1st I wanted to find the sets with just 3 consecutive even numbers and then build on that.Not sure how to counter the **at least 3** part of the problem !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part of the question you could use a counter to count consecutive even numbers in the list. If the number is not even you can reset the count to 0. If the counter is 3 then you've reached at least 3 consecutive evens and you can add to your set of evens count.

See below:

```
list1 = [1,2,4,6,8,11,2,8]
SetofEven = 0
count = 0
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    if list1[i] % 2 == 0:
        count += 1
    else:
        count = 0
    # Only increment set of even count once if 3 is reached
    if count == 3:
        SetofEven += 1

print(SetOfEven)
# Prints 1
```

#### Extracting the sets

If you also want the sets of numbers not just the count, you can get it from the `else` clause in my answer by checking if count is greater than 0:

```
my_evens_list = []

# ...

else:
    if count > 0:
        my_evens_list.append(list1[i - count:i])
    count = 0

# ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`&` is a **bitwise** AND operator, not a logical one. What you are looking for is a condition like this:

```
if a % 2 == b % 2 == c % 2 == 0
```

or like this:

```
if a % 2 == 0 and b % 2 == 0 and c % 2 == 0
```

Contrary to languages like C++, where **logical** AND uses the `&&` operator, in Python you use `and`.

Edit: as to the second part of the question, I don't think this approach will be fruitful, as such a loop shows you overlapping sequences of length three. You might be better of using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

# list of pairs (True/False, list of numbers)
groups = groupby(list1, lambda x: x % 2 == 0)

count = 0
for even, sequence in groups:
    if even and len(list(sequence)) >= 3:
        count += 1
```

`groupby` groups a sequence according to a predicate, so for

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 2, 8]
>>> list(groupby(list1, lambda x: x % 2 == 0))
[(False, [1]), (True, [2, 4, 6, 8]), (False, [11]), (True, [2, 8])]
# actually the second elements in pairs are not lists but iterators, but their contents are the same
```

Comment: How should I tackle the atleast 3 part of the question ?

Comment: @JapnitSethi I added an example solution using `groupby`